# Is there a good, maintained solution for Server Push with Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: gwt, push

The GWT RPC mechanism is great for client initiated communication. We're looking for a solid, supported way to do Push notifications from the server to the clients.  All the solutions we can find are several years old and don't seem to work with newer versions of Eclipse and GWT.

We're prepared to use the Google App Engine if that helps.

We can roll our own socket code if that helps, as well, but we are Java developers.  Writing JavaScript to do socket work would be a last resort, although if that's what it takes and there are examples we could probably handle it.

Any pointers to sample code or suggestions as to packages to use are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whoever voted to close: This is a good question, and it's defnitely about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Atmosphere Framework](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). They have a gwt20 module which works great with gwt.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are two possible solutions.

First you can use Errai. Errai has an event bus which also can be used on the server:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Messaging+API+Basics?_sscc=t

I did not use it, but think it is possible to do server push.
The second framework I know is gwt-comet:

https://github.com/rzschech/gwt-comet

I did not use one of them. But if I would look for a server push solution, I would give gwt-comet a try.

Comment: Yes, we are using Errai to push from the server to individual clients. You can also do a broadcast push to all clients.